# i am try exchange data between two textbox in vb.net using vs2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, richtextbox, copy-paste

I'm trying to change a textbox text dynamically from another textbox and  When i'm writing in the first textbox, the text that i'm writing must appare in the second textbox. but here problem is that i have not contain id or name destination text box Please help!and i have work in vb.net using vs2010

Comment: Welcome to SO. show us some code

Comment: i have no code please give me solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow. I will assume you're a complete newbie and will try to be as comprehensive as possible.
Right click on the first text box and choose properties. Go to the first property: (Name). This will give you the name of that text box. Now do the same for the second text box. Now, double click on the first text box. You will see two dropdown lists on top of your code window. The one on the left stores controls like textbox, form, etc., and one on the right shows the properties of the control. Select second textbox name from the first dropdown list and select TextChanged from the second dropdown list. You will get something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
```

Now add this to the above subroutine:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

I am assuming that your first textbox's name is TextBox1 and second textbox's name is TextBox2. These might be different in your code.
For more details about events, properties, and functions, I recommend you read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172576(v=vs.90).aspx. That article is based on Visual Studio 2008 but it is equally applicable for Visual Studio 2010 as well. You will also find additional references and samples on the MSDN Visual Basic site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2x7h1hfk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change TextBox1 and TextBox2 with the names of your textboxes:

```
   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                    Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
```